# Secure client token authentication for API

Tags: api, security, http, authentication, ssl

I have a mobile iOS application that I want to authenticate to a RESTful API.
Every user potentially has multiple devices linked to the same account.

So far I came up with the following:

**Client-side**

- Let user login with username/password
- Send username/password & unique device id to server
- Get authToken from server and set it in the HTTP Authentication header for each API call
- On logout, remove authToken

**Server-side**

- API uses SSL
- user has many associated devices
- devices are represented by unique device id and authToken
- each time the user changes password, regenerate all authTokens
- if a device is removed, delete authToken for that device

**Would that be a secure approach to access the API and manually add/revoke devices?**

Comment: So basically, session cookies.  Given that pretty much every web-based application uses this approach, I should certainly hope it's a secure approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a fairly standard approach. Google has [a document that describes this approach](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps) (a  majority of the document is geared toward getting the token from the server to the client so that may not be as useful to you). And some more [detailed description of bearer token authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).

You should see if the application framework you're writing the server in already supports an authentication mechanism like OAuth, so you won't have to write your own.